# Java Mail - XML and HTML Tables

Tags: java, html, xml, email

I have been trying to code a mail system which inserts data to a xml template and then regathers the template to send as a mail, this works perfectly but their is a issue with sending over HTML Tables. if the mail is set to text/html my tables work fine but my xml doesn't, same applies to text/plain where my xml works and my html doesn't. Now my email is meant to contain both xml styled template with html table data inside.

**XML File - Content**

```
<bodycontent>
   <text1></text1>
   <text2></text2>
   <table1></table1>
   <table2></table2>
</bodycontent>
```

**Setting data into elements XML**

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("text1").item(0).setTextContent("data1");
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("text2").item(0).setTextContent("data2");
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("table1").item(0).setTextContent("data3");
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("table2").item(0).setTextContent("data4");
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("projectnum").item(0).setTextContent("data5");
```

**getting data content from the xml**

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("bodycontent").item(0).getTextContent();
```

**Creating mail transport**

```
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
                    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                    message.setSubject(rs.getString("emailTitle"));
                    message.setContent(rs.getString("emailContent"), "text/plain");
                    Address[] from = InternetAddress.parse(SMTPMailFrom);
                    message.addFrom(from);
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(rs.getString("requestEmailAddress"))); //Send email To (Type email ID that you want to send)

                    transport.connect(SMTPMailHost, Integer.parseInt(SMTPMailPort), SMTP_tmp_user, SMTP_tmp_pass);
                    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));   
                    transport.close();
```

**Email Content Example**

I am currently passing in the table as a string but this won't work. How do i convert this so the output is a parsed html table?

```
Data 3 = "<table border=\"1\"><tr><td> Data 1</td></tr><tr><td> Data 2</td></tr><tr><td> Data 3</td></tr></table>";
```

If the output is plain, any spacing between the xml nodes is displayed correctly but tables are still in string style.

I am completely stuck on how to program a way round this? and ideas?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same problem or in the future.

To fix having html and xml in a java mail you need to use MultiBodyParts MIME*, Split the data down into plain and html sections and use the body part content type to distinguish.

Here is some research to help you.

[MIME - Subtypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative)

[Multipart Messages.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Multipart.html)

Good Luck!